# Counterexamples for the image of central,idempotent,invertible and nilpotent elements of a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, examples-counterexamples

I already proved that if i was given a surjective ring morphism f from R to S and   then if a∈R is invertible, central, idempotent,  or nilpotent, respectively then f(a) also is. But im looking for counterexample to show the reciprocal is not always true. Thanks

Comment: Maximally efficient solution: Let $S$ be the zero ring and $R$ to be the ring of polynomials in two non-commutative variables $x$ and $y$. Take $a=x$. Then $a$ is not invertible, not central, not idempotent, and not nilpotent, but $f(a)$ is invertible, central, idempotent, and nilpotent.

Answer (score 1):

Try $R=\Bbb Z$ for invertible, idempotent, nilpotent.

Can you find a noncommutative ring with a commutative quotient? It's not hard, but you may be unfamiliar with examples of or construction methods for noncommutative rings.